# Deferred method inside while loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop, jquery-deferred

I have a while loop inside which I call a deferred method and normal method both returns a value. The problem is the while loop going on with each iteration and the return value from deferred method and normal methods are not sequential. some return values of deferred method are coming late. How to make while loop wait till the deferred method return the value.

Please give me a solution am stuck in this for days.

Update: psuedo code

```
while(!stopProcess){
        var pageno=findpageno(param);
        findPageNoRecursively.done(pagenum){
                 pageno=pagenum;
             }
        return pageno;
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: if the while loop is having some asynchronous operations then you can't do that... you need to share your code for us to suggest any solution

Comment: Your pseudo code is wrong. You assign the result of `findpageno()` to `pageno` a variable defined in every iteration. After it you assign a done handler to a deferred and use the same variable name in that handler (i.e. you are hiding the previously defined `pageno` variable. This is definitely a mistake. And your deferred is also created in this loop or you are assigning done handlers to the same one? Try to break your code into small single responsibility functions and give a better explanation of the problem.

Comment: .done(pagenum){
                 pageno=pagenum;
             }
        return pageno; SyntaxError: Unexpected token { . Look at http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

Comment: This is completely unclear. You set `pageno` to the result of a synchronous function (`findpageno`), but apparently you are not even interested in that value because you want to "wait" until `pageno` is set by `findPageNoRecursively`. So which of the two `pageno` values are you actually interested in and why do you call the other function?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change an asynchronous method to synchronous because (for reasons that are not entirely clear to me) Javascript doesn't provide access to the event loop processing.

In other event-based programming environments you're able to write a "nested event loop" in which you can wait for an operation to complete while processing events. This is not possible in Javascript and your code is always requested to terminate back to the event loop that is hidden.

This is the reason for which for example in node.js the "Sync" variants for methods are provided: it's impossible in Javascript to write a `Sync` version given only the asynchronous one because there's no synchronous waiting primitive.

Comment: I don't think ranting about what JS can or cannot do is helpful. Plus, the OP seems confused about how asynchronous programming in JS works and about what he is trying to achieve in the first place. His question clearly indicates a misunderstanding on his part, it does not at all indicate he found a defect in the language.

Comment: @Tomalak: Mine is not a rant. I simply observed that the "nested event loop" concept is absent from Javascript and this has consequences, one of them making impossible converting a asynchronous function into a synchronous form (what the OP seemed to me being asking). For sure it's not simply unintentional but I don't know the reasons for that choice (I never investigated for them, though).

Comment: Okay, not a rant, then. :) I just wanted to provide some counter-weight so that the OP, when he reads your answer, does not get the impression what he wants cannot be done. He wants the wrong thing, that's all.

Comment: @6502, to be understood by javascript programmers, you will have to provide references to, or definitions of, "event loop" and "nested event loop". The concepts are completely alien to javascript, though we certainly talk about "events" and "loops" individually. I hope I come across as more interested than critical.